# не работает конструкция if ($query_string != “”) {set $no_cache 1; }

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

Пытаюсь подключить кеширование через FAST CGI + nginx
Все настроил, работает.
В nginx.conf кеширование включено по умолчанию set $no_cache 0;.
В настройке хоста site.ru.conf для определенных условий  кеширование отключается (set $no_cache 1;
Ставлю условие отключение кеширования при наличии GET аргументов:

```
if ($query_string != “”) {set $no_cache 1; }
```

При включении данного условия для главной страницы https://site/ru/ (сайт одностраничник) кеширование так же отключается.
При отсутствии условия кеширование исправно работает.
Как тогда правильно прописать запрос что бы при наличии любых аргументов GET кеширование отключалось?

Comment: А кавычки у вас там нормальные? Или как в вопросе?

Comment: Да, отлично, проблема была в неверных кавычках. Спасибо!!